# Update SQL command Syntax Error

Tags: c#, sql, syntax-error

I've checked and rechecked and looked over and over at it but can't understand what's wrong with it.
I have this code to make the insert that works fine:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@codigo", cal.CodEtiq.ToString()));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@data", cal.Data));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@entidade", cal.EntidadeCal));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@observacao", cal.Observacao));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@certificado", cal.Certificado));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@resultado", cal.Resultado));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@selecionar", cal.Selecionar));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@null", DBNull.Value));

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Movimento Ferramentas] " +
                  "(Codigo , [Data saida], [Entidade], [Data Ent], [GT EntT Nº], Estado, [GT Saida Nº], [Observações1], Requesitante, Certificado, Resultado, Seleccionar, [Tipo de Intervenção]) " + // columns
                  "VALUES (@codigo, @data , @entidade, null, null,  'Calibração', null, @observacao, null, @certificado, @resultado,   @selecionar , null)";
```

And now I have this code for the update that keeps giving me Invalid Arguments error.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@codigo", cal.CodEtiq.ToString()));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@data", cal.Data));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@entidade", cal.EntidadeCal));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@observacao", cal.Observacao));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@certificado", cal.Certificado));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@resultado", cal.Resultado));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@selecionar", cal.Selecionar));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@certificadoAnterior", certificadoAnterior));

cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE SET [Movimento Ferramentas] " +
                  "(Codigo = @codigo, " +
                "[Data saida] = @data, " +
                "[Entidade] = @entidade, " +
                "[Data Ent] = null, " +
                "[GT EntT Nº] = null," +
                "Estado = 'Calibração', " +
                "[GT Saida Nº] = null, " +
                "[Observações1] = @observacao," +
                "Requesitante = null," +
                "Certificado = @certificado, " +
                "Resultado = @resultado, " +
                "Seleccionar = @selecionar," +
                "[Tipo de Intervenção] = null) " +
                "WHERE Certificado = @certificadoAnterior";
```

So what is wrong with the update?

EDIT: As requested it'd be something like the following I think

```
String myCommand = "UPDATE SET [Movimento Ferramentas] (Codigo = @codigo, [Data saida] = @data, [Entidade] = @entidade, [Data Ent] = null, [GT EntT Nº] = null, Estado = 'Calibração', [GT Saida Nº] = null, [Observações1] = @observacao, Requesitante = null, Certificado = @certificado, Resultado = @resultado, Seleccionar = @selecionar, [Tipo de Intervenção] = null) WHERE Certificado = @certificadoAnterior";
```

Comment: Could you do like String myCommand = "your sql statement";

Be easier to look at if we can see what it's outputting

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Your edit is still incorrect, the table name needs to be between UPDATE and SET, i.e. `UPDATE [Movimento Ferramentas] SET`

Comment: @christiandev The edit was for Sythnet comment before I got any of the answers. Either way, it's working now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of the update goes roughly as follows:

```
UPDATE <table name>
SET <list of column expressions>
WHERE <condition>
```

Note that there are no parentheses around the list of the column expressions.

So you should rewrite your `UPDATE` like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Movimento Ferramentas] SET " + // <<== Changed the order
            "Codigo = @codigo, " +                        // <<== Removed (
            "[Data saida] = @data, " +
            "[Entidade] = @entidade, " +
            "[Data Ent] = null, " +
            "[GT EntT Nº] = null," +
            "Estado = 'Calibração', " +
            "[GT Saida Nº] = null, " +
            "[Observações1] = @observacao," +
            "Requesitante = null," +
            "Certificado = @certificado, " +
            "Resultado = @resultado, " +
            "Seleccionar = @selecionar," +
            "[Tipo de Intervenção] = null " +             // <<== Removed )
            "WHERE Certificado = @certificadoAnterior";
```

Comment: Good catch on the parentheses

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
UPDATE SET [Movimento Ferramentas] "
```

do

```
UPDATE [Movimento Ferramentas] SET "
```

Answer (score 2):

this is wrong update statement...Correct statement is below..

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Movimento Ferramentas] SET " +
              "Codigo = @codigo, " +
            "[Data saida] = @data, " +
            "[Entidade] = @entidade, " +
            "[Data Ent] = null, " +
            "[GT EntT Nº] = null," +
            "Estado = 'Calibração', " +
            "[GT Saida Nº] = null, " +
            "[Observações1] = @observacao," +
            "Requesitante = null," +
            "Certificado = @certificado, " +
            "Resultado = @resultado, " +
            "Seleccionar = @selecionar," +
            "[Tipo de Intervenção] = null " +
            "WHERE Certificado = @certificadoAnterior";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your [`UPDATE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) syntax is wrong.

```
UPDATE 
    [ TOP ( expression ) [ PERCENT ] ] 
    { { table_alias | <object> | rowset_function_limited 
         [ WITH ( <Table_Hint_Limited> [ ...n ] ) ]
      }
      | @table_variable    
    }
```

Table names should be on between `UPDATE` and `SET` parts.

Change your;

```
UPDATE SET [Movimento Ferramentas]
```

to

```
UPDATE [Movimento Ferramentas] SET
```

Full command should be like;

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE SET [Movimento Ferramentas] 
                  (Codigo = @codigo, 
                  [Data saida] = @data, 
                  [Entidade] = @entidade, 
                  [Data Ent] = null, 
                  [GT EntT Nº] = null,
                  Estado = 'Calibração', 
                  [GT Saida Nº] = null, 
                  [Observações1] = @observacao,
                  Requesitante = null,
                  Certificado = @certificado,
                  Resultado = @resultado, 
                  Seleccionar = @selecionar,
                  [Tipo de Intervenção] = null) 
                  WHERE Certificado = @certificadoAnterior";
```