# Update SQL command doesn't affect any rows

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update

As general question I'd like to ask what can result in an update sql command making no changes in the table without giving any error?

Now more specifically, I have an update with no errors, all variables containing correct values, there is at least one value that's different from the one in the table, the value in the WHERE clause existing in the table and no errors given. So what is possibly going wrong?

I'm working on Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 with an OleDB connection to MS Access 2010 (more precisly .accdb file)
Here is the code:

```
public int updateCert(Calibracao cal, string certificadoAnterior)
 {
 OleDbConnection l = OleDbConnectionDAO.createConnection();
 int result = 0;

  try
    {   
       l.Open();

       OleDbCommand cmd = l.CreateCommand();
       cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@data", cal.Data));
       cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@entidade", cal.EntidadeCal));
       cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@observacao", cal.Observacao));
       cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@certificado", cal.Certificado));
       cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@resultado", cal.Resultado));
       cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@selecionar", cal.Selecionar));
       cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@certificadoAnterior", certificadoAnterior));

       cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Movimento Ferramentas] SET " +
                 "[Data saida] = @data, " +
        "[Entidade] = @entidade, " +
        "Estado = 'Calibração', " +
        "[Observações1] = @observacao," +
        "Certificado = @certificado, " +
        "Resultado = @resultado " +
        "WHERE Certificado = @certificadoAnterior";

        result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        l.Close();
    }
     catch (Exception ex)
        {
            l.Close();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DAO Exception: " + ex.Message);
            return result;
        }
        return result;
```

}

EDIT: Corrected the SET, the issue remains

UPDATE: Problem solved with old school debugging removing everything then adding a field at the time. I don't what exactly was wrong but it ended up working. In case it helps someone else, this is how the code ended up:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@entidade", cal.EntidadeCal));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@data", cal.Data));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@certificado", cal.Certificado));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@resultado", cal.Resultado));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@observacao", cal.Observacao));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@certificadoAnterior", certificadoAnterior));

cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Movimento Ferramentas] SET " +
            "[Entidade] = @entidade, " +
            "[Data saida] = @data, " +
            "Certificado = @certificado, " +
            "Resultado = @resultado, " +
            "[Observações1] = @observacao " +
            "WHERE Certificado = @certificadoAnterior";
```

Comment: Datatype mismatch maybe? Post all the relevant code, please.

Comment: `UPDATE SET [Movimento Ferramentas]` is wrong for a start, it should be `UPDATE [Movimento Ferramentas] SET ...`

Comment: It might also help to know what kind of database engine this is going to.  (You never know.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767534/update-sql-command-syntax-error
And there it was laready mentioned to use the correct syntax for your update statement...

Comment: @oerkelens That was an issue already resolved, this is a different one of there being no errors and no update. Or should I reedit the code adn questions there?

Comment: You've confirmed plugging in the values and it doesn't update anything? It sounds like an issue with the where clause causing the statement to not hit anything.

Comment: Ah, I was thrown off by the copy / paste error :)

Comment: @BillMartin Extending some more, I have a datagridview that gets filled with the table's values, after that the user can click a row or cell and it fills some textfields in the same windows form then the user can edit those fields. Afterwards I construct "Calibracao cal" with the data in those fields and make the update with it. The "string certificadoAnterior" I get from the datagridview rigth after it is filled. And I know the values are correct because I checked them during debug.

Comment: @oerkelens the SET thing is fixed, I copy pasted that part wrong from the other post to avoid having to give the spacing on everything for it to appear as code since the only changes I made since i fixed that issue were removing the fields I was putting as null since there was no point in updating them in my situation and changing the place of the SET

Comment: What type of database?

Comment: @BillMartin Directly, Access 2010 one. More precisely .accdb file.

Answer (score 4):

You have to create the command text before attempting to add parameters:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Movimento Ferramentas] " +
                 "SET [Data saida] = @data, " +
                     "[Entidade] = @entidade, " +
                     "Estado = 'Calibração', " +
                     "[Observações1] = @observacao," +
                     "Certificado = @certificado, " +
                     "Resultado = @resultado " +
                     "WHERE Certificado = @certificadoAnterior";


cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@data", cal.Data));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@entidade", cal.EntidadeCal));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@observacao", cal.Observacao));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@certificado", cal.Certificado));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@resultado", cal.Resultado));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@selecionar", cal.Selecionar));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@certificadoAnterior", certificadoAnterior));
```

Also, your update syntax is wrong, the format is:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

Comment: If I remove the @ sign won't there be a conflict for example in the 
"Certificado = @certificado, " ?

Comment: the parameter would look for `@` then assign the value to it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50xtbfet.aspx

Comment: Tried that, still not updating nor anything (result value is 0. And I'm sure it didn't update without me noticing because I have a message box that's supposed to show when the that method returns > 0)

Comment: what is `selecionar` I dont see it in your update query, other than that I don't see anymore problem with your code

Comment: Sounds like you need some good old fashioned debugging. Remove all but 1 parameter from your param list and sql statement and see if that value gets updated. If so, add the next, and so on. Could be a type mismatch issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use ? rather than the parameter name:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Movimento Ferramentas] " +
                 "SET [Data saida] = ?, " +
        "[Entidade] = ?, " +
        "Estado = 'Calibração', " +
        "[Observações1] = ?," +
        "Certificado = ?, " +
        "Resultado = ? " +
        "WHERE Certificado = ?";
```

Make sure your params are added to the list in the order they're referenced in the statement. Some database providers allow the @ and some require the ?. Just depends on what you're hitting, like Adam said above.

Comment: As for database provider is a bit complex. Using an OleDB connection to connect to an access datasource which has a linked table from a Oracle server/database.

Comment: Tried that, still not updating nor anything (result value is 0. And I'm sure it didn't update without me noticing because I have a message box that's supposed to show when the that method returns > 0)